# Way to get accelerometer reading every x seconds?

Tags: android, accelerometer

To be able to do some accurate calculations that I want for my app, I need to be able to get an accelerometer reading every 100ms. I haven't found a way to do this on android, it seems like the only way to get accelerometer readings is to put a listener that can listen at different intervals. Basically, is there a way to get a reading at exact intervals?

-Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would register a Accelerator listener and then in the listener, I would read the system time and only if 1 second is passed, you can update you further methods.

Comment: Yeah, this works, I just didnt know if there was something already built in.

Answer (score 1):

The solution presented seems more battery consuming than an alternative I have used in my projects. It goes like this:

1. Set an Alarm (`android.app.AlarmManager`) that would be `setRepeating` every `x` seconds.
2. In the `onReceive` of the alarm `registerListener` with the sensor setting of your convenience.
3. In the `SensorEventListener`'s `onSensorChanged` use the `event`'s values as you need. Then `unregisterListener`.

Steps 2 and 3 will repeat every `x` seconds.

I wish I would paste in all the code but it's quite long and intertwined with other functionality and I am sure you can find all the details online.

Answer (score 0):

Put a Thread.sleep() in the listener to throttle down the readings. They run on a separate thread.